# Creating Multiple URLs to 1 page

Tags: php, drupal, hyperlink

On Drupal I want to do this:

If I create an article I have the option to choose if it is a "persbericht" or not. So if I choose Yes to "Persbericht" then create these urls www.blabla.com/persbericht/nieuws/article and www.blabla.com//nieuws/article

else if not then create only one link : www.blabla.com//nieuws/article .

If I say yes to the option "persbericht" then it will create 2 urls to one page one persbericht/nieuws and the other /nieuws and if I say no it will create only one url to /nieuws.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could use taxonomy to mark the article as persbericht,
then in pathauto(I think), you could specify that if the taxonomy is present then it should be

persbericht/news/article

then when the taxonomy is not chosen persbericht won't be part of the url.

To create the second url, you might need som hacking in your template.php file or create a custom module for that.

Here is information about how to create a new url programmatically
[Drupal: How do I programatically create a URL alias for a node that already has an alias on node save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811065/drupal-how-do-i-programatically-create-a-url-alias-for-a-node-that-already-has)